# Wordpress Meta Query very slow with NOT EXISTS comparison

Tags: meta-query

I need to get posts which do not have a certain meta key.

```php
    function handle_empty_date_paid($query, $query_vars)
    {
        if (!empty($query_vars['not_paid'])) {
            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => '_date_paid',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            );
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

and then

```php
$posts = get_posts([
    'limit' => 30,
    'not_paid' => '1'
]);
```

This query is very slow. Is there any way to make it work? Comparision '=0' does not work in this case. The opposite query is date_paid => '>0' works ok and fast.
I think that the slow performance is caused by 'NOT EXISTS'. Is there any way to change that?

#Edit

This is a little bit faster

```php
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_date_paid'");
$exclude = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
   $exclude[] = $row->post_id;
}
$args['post__not_in'] = $exclude;
```

Comment: WooCommerce questions & 3rd party plugin/theme dev support Q's are off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: Woocommerce has an API you can use for that, one of the endpoints is to retrieve orders, you can all use a payload to filter what orders you want to get https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders

Comment: You didn’t understand the question